# WPA2-Enterprise won't work with Win8.1 Client?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, radius, wpa2

I'm the administrator of a relatively small wireless network, with unmanaged, BYOD devices that connect via WPA2-Enterprise (PEAP/MSCHAP authentication), controlled by a cloud RADIUS server. Yes, I understand this may sound like overkill for a small network, but we've had some unauthorized password sharing incidents and this mitigates the impact of those incidents. Users are allowed to connect any devices they want using their personal user ID (no MAC filtering/authentication), however all MAC addresses are logged and I simply roll their password if I see something suspicious. Most clients are humming along just fine, but one user's Win8.1 laptop suddenly quit connecting one day. Even after I had the user forget the network, they still get a very vague error about not being able to connect to the network with no explanation. They were able to get on the guest network (WPA2-PSK, broadcast from same wireless equipment) as well as their own mobile hotspot. This is especially strange as it worked fine and suddenly quit one day. Any suggestions how this problem could be resolved? Is there a way we could blow out any trace of having been on the network before and start clean?